# Probability of an occurrence with a pool that can have duplicates

Tags: probability

I am in a beginning statistics class and am having a problem with this problem. My issue is the "duplicates" part.

### The Problem

I have a pool of numbers, 1 - 10.

I have 5 slots.

I draw 5 numbers from the pool to fill those five slots. I can have duplicate numbers. 

What are the odds that I draw a set of 5 numbers with no duplicates?




I can figure out simple probability, but how do I determine the total number of possibilities for the denominator and the "event" for the numerator to get my percentage if I am allowed duplicate numbers in my set?


What I've tried:

- looking at google and this forum for tips on helping me solve/understand the math behind this, but I don't think I am wording my query correctly.

Comment: Hint: Denominator: You have 10 possible outcomes for one slot. Then you have ___ possible outcomes for 5 slots.

Comment: Does the original pool have an equal amount of each number 1- 10? I think the term you are looking for is "sampling with replacement"

Comment: Thanks @callculus! I can work with this. @Daphna, sorry for the confusion, the pool is just 1-10. One occurrence of each number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be thought of as an example of [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), which concerns the probability that, in a set of n randomly chosen people, some pair of then will have the same birthday.

$$
P(\text{draw a set of 5 numbers with no duplicates}) = P(\text{all 5 numbers are different})
                                              = {10! \over {(10-5)!10^5 }}
$$
$$
P(\text{draw a set of 5 numbers with duplicates}) = 1 - {10! \over {(10-5)!10^5 }}                                            
$$